# Rails update.js.erb not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a form in rails that will edit an existing question via ajax.

After the form is submitted and the question has been updated, the update method in the controller renders update.js.erb, which will hide the form again.

My problem is that the javascript code in update.js.erb is not executing at all.

I know that the file is rendering because it shows up in the server output, and when I put a

```
<% raise params %>
```

into it, it works.

However, even the simplest

```
alert('hello');
```

has no effect in the same file.

I've ruled out javascript and jquery configuration issues because the same code works perfectly in my edit.js.erb file. It's just not working in update.js.erb.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Firebug shows no errors. Here is the response in firebug's network panel:

```
alert('hello');
$('#question_body').replaceWith('<h4><p>jhsdfjhdsb k jdfs j fjfhds <strong>jfshaflksd;hf sdldfs l fdsalkhdfskhdfs</strong>;fd lfdksh hfdjaadfhsjladfhsjadfs ;df sjldfsj dfas hafdsj fdas ;ldfas ldfs df dl;hdf fdh ;fdj ;lfads</p></h4>');
```

def update

**Edit 2:**

This is the controller action:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      format.html { redirect_to @question, :flash => { :success => 'Question was successfully updated.' } }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js {}
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Checkout the response in firebug's network panel. What does it show?

Comment: Added the response to the question. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: show did you build the ajax into your form? If for instance you just call $.ajax(..) but do nothing with the response nothing will be executed, opposed to for instance using jQuerys getScript (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: It's built into the form via `:remote => true`. The form is submitting fine, and the changes are recording in the database. It's the javascript that is called after the update method calls update.js.erb that is not working.

Comment: post your update controller action

Comment: I just added the controller action to the question, but I do not believe that is the problem because update.js.erb is being rendered and rails code in the file such as `<% raise params %>` are working - it's just the javascript & jquery code in that file that are giving me headaches.

Comment: Did you escape the html in your javascript file? Try copy pasting your response and running it manuall in firebug console. Try to see if that gives any errors.

Comment: The code works as intended when I paste it into the console. No errors.

Comment: Should this be a partial? ie. _update.js.erb

Comment: Have you ever found out? I have exactly the same problem - just with a create action. Also, if I run the ajax call via its 'own method', I have no problem. I think it must have something to do with RESTfulness and the actions create and update. I used to be able to do this with earlier rails versions.

Answer (score 55):

In your `$.ajax` call make sure to set the `dataType` option to `"script"` otherwise the response could be interpreted in other ways and thus not executed as JS.

Comment: perfect answer! incase some one needs to use it with `button_to` : `form: { "data-type" => "script" }`

Answer (score 38):

Do you work with haml, or html.erb? If the former, then this might be the solution:

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...
  format.js {render layout: false}
end
```

I had the exact same problem, found this question early on, took another hour or so of Googling to find this question on StackOverflow that led me to it: [jQuery + Ajax + Haml. js.erb files not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412375/jquery-ajax-haml-js-erb-files-not-firing)

Comment: ```{render layout: false}``` has wasted my 3 hours for same problem. After adding it, it works fine. Thaks

Comment: After days of struggling, this worked for me :) Thanks

Comment: Works here too. But why do I need `render layout: false` here? I've already specified a layout at the top of the controller file. I've used the exact same pattern (submitting via `remote: true` and modifying the page in `create.js.erb`) in several places without ever using `render layout: false` before.

Comment: you are my hero

Answer (score 4):

In your update.js.erb file you need to escape javascript wherever you execute ruby code.

```
$('.container').empty().append('<%=
  escape_javascript(
    render 'update'
  )
%>')
```

This is what solved it for me ...

Comment: You can also escape javascript by using `j`. Example: `$('.container').html("<%= j render 'update' %>");`

Answer (score 2):

This issue isn't just because of **Controller** side. It is also can be in the **View** side which is you didn't clarify the data-type of your post request.

Make sure in your console that the request is treated as **JS**.

Reference:  [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555267/rails-3-link-to-remote-is-not-triggering-rjs/25016468#25016468)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found this page. I tried methods listed here but found no luck. While later the following method solve my issue.

My originally code was:

```
$('#html_id').html('<%=@ruby_variable%>');
```

And I updated it to:

```
$('#html_id').html('<%=raw @ruby_variable.to_json%>');
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Jesus, you were right. Any idea why it fails silently instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it is!  (solution for rails 4)

If you have in your ajax call parameters that are not in your permitted list, the record gets saved, you get no error messages about the 'not permitted' parameters, but the update.js.erb won't run - even though your terminal will feed back 'Rendered update.js.erb etc'

If the extra parameter is an attribute in your model, just permit it.

The simplest way to permit non model parameter is to add in your model:

```
  attr_accessor :paramKeyTroublesome
```

Then you can also permit it in the controller.

in the $ajax call, data needs to be hashed up properly:

```
  data: {model_name: {paramKey1: value, paramKeyTroublesome: value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more problem to be aware of is an error in your update.js file. Nothing will execute if there are any syntax errors. You can check this by going to your browser inspector and enabling `Log XMLHttpRequests` Then reviewing the output js file.