# rails 4, nested resource doesn't updates without page refreshing, using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-resources

So, I'm having Events model which has_many Questions. Relation is the same as in  Post->Comment. I've tried to implement some Ajax for Questions, but it seems like I'm missing something, because View doesn't updates without refreshing the page. The same problem with delete method.

Here's my question_controller.rb:

```
def create
 @question = @event.questions.create(question_params)
 @question.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
 if @question.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to event_path(@event) }
    format.js # render questions/create.js.erb
  end
 else
  render 'events/show'
 end
end
```

Question _form.haml:

```
= simple_form_for [@event, @event.questions.new], remote: true do |f|
 = f.input :content, label: 'Your question:', id: 'question_content'
 = f.submit class: 'submit_btn'
```

Question partial _question.haml:

```
%h4
    = question.content
```

This is how it looks in Events show.haml:

```
%section#question_section
 %h1 Questions:
  #questions
   = render @event.questions

#question-form
 %h1 Submit a question:
 = render 'questions/form'
```

And create.js.erb file:

```
$('#questions').append("<%= j render partial: @question %>");
$('#question_content').val('');
```

I've tried few different tutorials, but always had the same problem. View updates only after refreshment. Also it is my second post on Stackoverflow so would be grateful for any suggestions if something is wrong with it.

**EDIT 1**: mostly I've been following this tutorial: https://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2015/3/18/rails-jquery-ajax

**EDIT 2**: create.js.erb seems not to respond, tried to test it with alerts or console log, but without any success. After triggering a button in the console having: "Processing by QuestionsController#create as JS" (so it runs a proper file, but file itself doesn't executes any code). Have no idea why that happening.

Comment: can you confirm that create.js.erb does get executed? and that your question has content. (i.e. its not just appending empty `h4` tags that would look like its not appending at all)

Comment: seems not, I've tried to console.log some text and it doesn't appears after triggering create button.

also tired: format.js {render action: "create"} in controller

Comment: are there errors in your server console? what does the server response say it rendered?

Comment: it says: Processing by QuestionsController#create as JS and then some transactions (insert into, select, update) without errors.

Comment: oh and: Rendered questions/_question.haml (0.4ms)
  Rendered questions/create.js.erb within layouts/application

Comment: Try to check if  the element ``h1`` with the id ``questions`` is unique in your ``show.haml`` view template. I had the same kind of problem and the reason was because there were more than one elements with the same id. There should only be one element with a specific id and if there are several of them, JS will get confused.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but unfortunately it's not the case, id is unique. create.js.erb just doesn't executes any code and I'm still struggling to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was because of HAML. Had to change my format.js line in the controller to:

```
formta.js { render layout: false }
```

Here's the thread that helped to solve this: [Rails update.js.erb not executing javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936633/rails-update-js-erb-not-executing-javascript)