# Rails jQuery Unexpected Token "<"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code is

**app/views/rooms/photo_upload.html.slim**

```
.panel-body
    .container
      .row
        .col-md-offset-3.col-md-6
          = form_for @room, url: room_photos_path(@room), method: "post", html: {multipart: true} do |f|
            .row
              .form-group
                span.btn.btn-default.btn-file.text-babu 
                  i.fa.fa-cloud-upload aria-hidden='true'
                  |  Select Photos

                  = file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true
            .text-center
              = f.submit "Add Photos", class:"btn btn-form"
    #photos
      = render "photos/photos_list"
```

**app/views/photos/_photos_list.html.slim**

```
  - if @photos.count > 0 
  br/
  br/
  .row
    - @photos.each do |photo|
      .col-md-4
        .panel.panel-default  
          .panel-heading.preview
            = image_tag photo.image.url()
          .panel-body
            span.pull-right
              = link_to room_photo_path(photo.room_id, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "are you sure?"} do
                i.fa.fa-trash-o aria-hidden="true"
```

**photos_controller.rb**

```
 def destroy 
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    room = @photo.room

    @photo.destroy
    @photos = Photo.where(room_id: room.id)

    respond_to :js
  end
```

**app/views/photos/destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render 'photos_list' %>")
```

This is the error that I am getting when trying to remove a photo from the list.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:246)
    at rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:173
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:230)
```

The response I get is this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><title>AirBnbClone</title><meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="ihYTPYHKu9/DohfdcD4KvS603LsB8818TJSxl8TMjuCMkNpn/awkfloDXpwaH3l4JWoDQC48s+hqN8g8C8EArw==" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/font-awesome.self-2a86d2017f4b74f22943750b3b50b9cb753581bab96cbdaaf2df53f4c04c995b.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-c4cfecca9755bfcd96db45091a22a37633282ede14636f0922eafb0e437734b9.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" /><script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/room.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-6ad2488465135ab731a045a8ebbe3ea2fc501aed286042496eda1664fdd07ba9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-742145c5bb847aafdadc6e339be795628f8bc25f177e851f03a8c42278eb0312.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-126ac9bf0e7f2d8568f8da3a00fd5f0fac6eae0946331003370161fbf8d7975e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-e47323f363ceb3dc0bdbce05e36e709ed428e339833a41140a85cb0af24b8127.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-2eb697f62b587bb786ff940d82dd4be88cdeeaf13ca128e3da3850c5fcaec301.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-561cca1cbaf67474e01e9536f106bad541594860a6df997004591c1c1957a147.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-3e78617ade5663314b7ee0ea10375a5b34d59ffbade44939e3f2a4e4ef2019b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-5bf7078b682f8b131332eefa46b45fa5eff2eca745fc0d03e2991450888f7c28.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-6d6f1a7fc5c8aabf3547fa1b794fab6268f54bc55ad815e55873c71f52513517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-969f3c5f48cdf1e439c7fa1154c13b948715f5c689f87837c0b64521d3b46ef6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-05afb177e08f98997ccfc84fa08a215e4b27d48d5fe4d049080675e9dffd8199.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-0aa93860b59fe7393f1dd490f54b3cb994f9d6155adffce034d4e14ae361b041.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/toastr.self-cd4d0b085c13a2d904a1272152dc0645a9261e6ca5cfc429a786b3e6465406df.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-d9c1df0d36a69bf8167ebb20070284ed3c5f931e7f6efe185b0936aad00629a6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet" /></head><body><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Air Pikachu</a></div><div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar"><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li class="dropdown"><a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"><img class="img-circle avatar-small" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e94a1ba848f7d983300ca174220cb426.jpg?d=identical&amp;s=150" alt="E94a1ba848f7d983300ca174220cb426" />&nbsp;Alberto Montalesi<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#"> Manage listings</a></li><li><a href="#"> List your space</a></li><li><a href="#"> Your reservations</a></li><li><a href="#"> Your trips</a></li><li class="divider" role="separator"></li><li><a href="/profile">Edit Profile</a></li><li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a></li></ul></li></ul></div></div></nav><div class="container">$('#photos').html("<br /><br /><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-4\"><div class=\"panel panel-default\"><div class=\"panel-heading preview\"><img src=\"/system/photos/images/000/000/033/original/Screenshot_from_2017-11-16_14-44-05.png?1511873581\" alt=\"Screenshot from 2017 11 16 14 44 05\" /><\/div><div class=\"panel-body\"><span class=\"pull-right\"><a data-confirm=\"are you sure?\" data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/rooms/1/photos/33\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"><\/i><\/a><\/span><\/div><\/div><\/div><div class=\"col-md-4\"><div class=\"panel panel-default\"><div class=\"panel-heading preview\"><img src=\"/system/photos/images/000/000/034/original/Screenshot_from_2017-11-28_13-40-18.png?1511873595\" alt=\"Screenshot from 2017 11 28 13 40 18\" /><\/div><div class=\"panel-body\"><span class=\"pull-right\"><a data-confirm=\"are you sure?\" data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/rooms/1/photos/34\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"><\/i><\/a><\/span><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>")

</div></body></html>
```

The partial does not render once I click the delete button and I get this error. Any idea what is causing it? Thanks for the help

Comment: try this `$('#photos').html("<%= escape_javascript render('photos_list') %>")`

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy: `j` is the short-hand for `escape_javascript`

Comment: Oh am sorry, i never knew this. Thanks for info. @alberto montalesi

Comment: How does your view for destroy look?

Comment: check the response using your browser's inspector, maybe you have some error serverside and it's responding with an error page

Comment: Can you add what you see as response in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: add layout => false like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943533/why-do-i-need-render-layout-false-in-my-rails-controller-action#40943751