# Can render javascript from controller but can't render .js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a button that submits a form remotely with Ajax using the rails built in helpers:

```
  button_to 'Delete Document', [:proofreader, proofreading_job, proofread_document], 
               method: :delete, 
               remote: true,  
               class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", 
               data: { disable_with: "Deleting document..." }
```

When the form is submitted to the controller I can cause an alert to show as follows:

```
def destroy
  @proofread_document.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: "alert('The username to be displayed is:')"}
  end
end
```

However when I want to render the destroy.js.erb file which has no code in it yet I get the following error in the browser:

```
def destroy
  @proofread_document.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-ed0b535c2816e34ce8dee0346bd17387dffd4873cb347fa9a8b267dae6f7f41b.js?body=1:257)
    at rails-ujs.self-ed0b535c2816e34ce8dee0346bd17387dffd4873cb347fa9a8b267dae6f7f41b.js?body=1:186
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-ed0b535c2816e34ce8dee0346bd17387dffd4873cb347fa9a8b267dae6f7f41b.js?body=1:241)
```

How can I fix this problem its stopped all development on this project.

Comment: try to use :layout => false as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943533/why-do-i-need-render-layout-false-in-my-rails-controller-action#40943751

Comment: That did it. Could you post your response as an answer. There are a few other questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532155/rails-jquery-unexpected-token?rq=1 that could benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<` charecter comes from layout file.
You can use `layout: false` with `render`.

```
def destroy
  @proofread_document.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of frustration. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use `layout: false`

```
def destroy
  @proofread_document.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: "alert('The username to be displayed is:')", layout: false }
  end
end
```

Worked fine:

[image]